# Remove 'Webpage Dialog' from 'showModalDialog' window using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, showdialog

Somewhere in page, I use

`onclick="window.showModalDialog("http://rauf-thecoder.blogspot.com/");"` .

It will show the following.
[image]

How can I remove the **Webpage Dialog** text from the title bar :( I am happy to use `jQuery` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot remove it (it's kind of a visual cue to the user that they are still in a web browser) as it displays the `<title>` tag of the page they are on. So obviously you cannot remove it if you display a site that you do not control.

If it's your web page that you control, just pad the `<title>` tag with spaces, or invisible characters until it pushes "Webpage Dialog" off screen inside the title bar.